# UWP Windows Store App listing says "Offers in-app purchases". But my app doesnt have any

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store, windows-dev-center

I have uploaded my UWP application to the windows store.

My app says the following:

> - Offers in-app purchases

**Screenshot:**

[image]

But my app doesn't have any in-app purchases!

I'm sure this is something I must have missed in the `Package.appmanigest` or in the Windows store submission. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does it have add-ons? Did you check **This product allows users to make purchases, but does not use the Windows Store commerce system.** in the **Properties** section of your submission? Would you mind sharing a link to your app?

Comment: @A.Milto It has got **This product allows users to make purchases, but does not use the Windows Store commerce system.** checked in the Properties section of the submission. I probably checked it by accident. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my application had:

> **This product allows users to make purchases, but does not use the Windows Store commerce system.**

checked in the Properties section of the submission. Unchecking this fixed the issue